# PuTTy wrongly display nethack ncurses characters as chinese character "贩"

Tags: ssh, putty, ncurses, character-set

Using PuTTy to ssh connect to `nethack@hardfought.org`. This is the game evilhack, but I think nethack is the same, using the curses interface, which I think is ncurses.

[image: interface image]

It should be fine, but those 2 dots display a Chinese character "贩" instead, which is really weird, the font is Consolas, and in the picture the character set is UTF8, but if I change to cp437 or ISO-8859-1, these "贩"s still exist, I try to change all those settings in the Translation page, but none helps.

Those dots have dark or light foreground color, I think maybe color or something caused this problem? And it seems other nethack players don't have this problem, I'm not sure if it's because my Windows 10 was using Chinese, but I think now it's English first.

Above that, when I use bitvise client or windows terminal to connect, this display problem doesn't appear, the interface displays fine.